# SonarQube Complaint Either remove this useless object instantiation of class or use it

Tags: c#, object, sonarqube

I'm trying to fix this bug that I get from SonarQube but their solution suggestion is not quite helpful for my case.
The suggestion that I'm getting from them is: "There is no good reason to create a new object to not do anything with it. Most of the time, this is due to a missing piece of code and so could lead to unexpected behavior in production."

Any suggestions on how this to be handled will be appreciated.

```
private RootElement GetParentAsRoot(Element element, string method) {
        if (element.Parent == null) {
            new RootElement(element, NewControlsNotifier);
       //Either remove this useless object instantiation of class 'RootElement' or use it.
        }
        var root = element.Parent as RootElement;
        if (root == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException(method + " method is applicable only on top-most element");
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that's causing this issue is this:

```
new RootElement(element, NewControlsNotifier);
```

You are creating a `RootElement` with new operator but ignored its result. You should either remove object creation completely or use the object you created.

Try this if you want to return your object:

```
private RootElement GetParentAsRoot(Element element, string method) {
        if (element.Parent == null) {
            return new RootElement(element, NewControlsNotifier);
        }
        var root = element.Parent as RootElement;
        if (root == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException(method + " method is applicable only on top-most element");
        }
        return root;
    }
```